# can't stop this recursive settimeout function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made this recursive set timeout function to send time for each game room but when the time finishes i cannot stop the function. i tried the clear timeout but it did not help so if anyone would help me.

```
setTimeout(function GameTime() {
    io.in(Rooms[picked].name).emit('PlayTime', timeleft);
    timeleft.x--; // HERE WHERE I DECREMENT THE TIME
    setTimeout(GameTime, 1000)
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Show how you try to clear timeout.

Comment: You can use a recursive setTimeout, but you might want to look at setInterval instead,.   btw. You can't clear a setTimeout or setInterval if you don't store it's return value, something your not doing above.

Comment: You're creating infinite timeouts! Are you sure you didn't meant `setInterval`?

Comment: [link] (https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval#summary)
this link describes why i used the settimeout as setinterval makes a delay over time and as for you @dsfq i could not not know when to return the value of the settimeout that is why i got stuck

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not stopping the loop, you has to stop it using the function `clearTimeout`.

A better approach for your scenario is using the function `setInterval`:

```js
var x = 3;
var intervalId = setInterval(function GameTime() {
    //io.in(Rooms[picked].name).emit('PlayTime', timeleft);
    //timeleft.x--; // HERE WHERE I DECREMENT THE TIME
    x--;
    if (x < 0)  {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      console.log('finished!');
      return;
    }    
    
    console.log('looping!');
}, 1000)
```

Comment: the setinterval does not run smoothly over time and it makes a delay as i explained.

Comment: @seifeldin  Your code your showing above is never going to have a problem with setInterval,.. There is no way that is going to take more than 1 second to process.  Chained setTimeouts are handy when something may take a long time to process, you don't want another trigger to fire again while this is happening and instead want to skedule it when the current task has finished.

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to the setTimeout you want to clear:

```js
let timeoutId, gameTimeoutId

timeoutId = setTimeout(function GameTime() {
  console.log('GameTime')
  gameTimeoutId = setTimeout(GameTime, 1000)
}, 1000)

setTimeout(function GameTime() {
  clearTimeout(timeoutId)
  clearTimeout(gameTimeoutId)
}, 5000)
```

This snippet will call `GameTime` each 1 second and after 5 seconds it removes the interval loop

As an alternative to this is to use setInterval, this will simplify you code considerable:

```js
const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  console.log('GameTime')
  // do stuff 
}, 1000)

setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(intervalId)
}, 5000)
```

Comment: For consistency you might want to store the return value of your first setTimeout, in case a cancel was requests before the first second.  eg.  `let intervalId = setTimeout(func...`  should do it.

Comment: @Keith makes sense. Updated the answer ;)

Comment: the simplified one worked fine i just need adjust the time according to my needing. thank you so much

Comment: @a--m you should change the clear interval to cleartimeout to work i modified it and it works fine. thanks again

Comment: Well spotted @seifeldin , the code snippet did work though, but I've changed the code with your proposal.

Comment: You assign to `intervalId` but you clear `timeoutId` which is never set.  There is no need to use a second variable, you could use the `gameTimeoutId` for both, using only one `clearTimeout` because `intervalId` is finished anyway when `gameTimeoutId` is set the first time.